# Change Task Manager Image Name Display

Tags: java

I have a jar file which is developed in java(hi.jar) 
while running it in task manager it showing like javaw.exe, but i want to change it to hi.exe. 
can anybody help me 
thanks

Comment: You can't really, unless you can use one of the executable wrappers, I know exe4j can do this

Answer (score -1):

Enter the Task-Manager, find your process.
Right-Click it -> Properties
Right click the Process again (leave Properties-Window open) and kill the Process.
Now go to Properties-Window again and enter "General"-Tab.
Change the Name to hi.exe and apply it.

For you it will work but I dont think it is not possible to change it in the CODE or something.

Comment: No if you are Administrator, TaskManager should remember it. But it will only work for you (User) and your Computer.